# Installing Cisco AnyConnect on CentOS 7

Tags: centos, cisco-vpn-client

I have installed Cisco AnyConnect on CentOS 7. When I try to connect I get an error:

> /opt/cisco/anyconnect/bin/vpndownloader: error while loading shared libraries: libpangox-1.0.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

I've Googled it, but there is no valid solution to this problem.

Does anybody use Cisco AnyConnect on CentOS 7 and know how to solve this issue?

Comment: Did you try as mentioned http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/security/vpn_client/anyconnect/anyconnect40/release/notes/b_Release_Notes_AnyConnect_4_0.html#reference_01BC5975E0F944509D05EFA10912245F in AnyConnect release docs ?

Answer (score 6):

It looks like Cisco AnyConnect requires pangox-compat. CentOS 7 does not ship with pangox, however it is in the [EPEL](http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/EPEL) (Extra Packages for Enterprise Linux) repository. You should be able to run these two commands to install the missing package:

```
# yum install http://mirror.ancl.hawaii.edu/linux/epel/7/x86_64/e/epel-release-7-5.noarch.rpm

# yum install pangox-compat
```

Good luck!

Comment: yum install epel-release; yum install pangox-compat pangox-compat-devel

Comment: Thanks Ben. Under Fedora 23, just using yum install pangox-compat pangox-compat-devel  command worked.

Comment: The package epel-release-7-5.noarch.rpm is not available anymore change the URL to 7-8.

http://mirror.ancl.hawaii.edu/linux/epel/7/x86_64/e/epel-release-7-8.noarch.rpm

Comment: This helped me locate libpangox on Ubuntu for the same issue. Thanks!